# facing issue while displaying various views in same page using angular 2+

Tags: angular

here i am trying to display the 3 different views in the same page buy button press but here i unable to proceed for that if press 2nd view and i am getting the 3rd view also

below is my code:

```
<div class="container">


    <div *ngIf="showData">
         <p>This is page 1</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="testOne()">Page 1
         </button>
           <br>
           <br>
         <button (click)="page3()" >click here for page 3</button>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div *ngIf="!showData">
        <p> this is page 2</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="back()">Back to page1</button>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="!showData">
       <p>Page 3</p>
    </div>  

</div>  

 showData = true;


  testOne(){
    this.showData = false;
  }

  back(){
    this.showData = true;
  }

  page3(){
    this.showData = false;
  }
```

stackblitz url  :   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vyw1cs

Comment: Yes as per your code it will display 2 and 3 at once. You can use three different parameter to show and hide views.

Comment: could u modify the stack where it should be done

Answer (score 1):

you have to do like below:

link is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wphb4k

Answer (score 0):

One method is to set your `*ngIf` to evaluate if it's on a page number, then act accordingly:

**html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div *ngIf="showData == 1">
         <p>This is page 1</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showData = 2">Page 2
         </button>
         <button (click)="showData = 3" >page 3</button>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div *ngIf="showData == 2">
        <p> this is page 2</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showData = 1">Page 1
         </button>
         <button (click)="showData = 3" >page 3</button>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="showData == 3">
       <p>Page 3</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showData = 1">Page 1
         </button>
         <button (click)="showData = 2" >page 2</button>
    </div>  

</div>
```

**component.ts**

`showData = 1`

**stackblitz example**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9scudq

Comment: i am already using a button event to display to fire another event and here now what happens is now i have to use 2 button events